# Airflow | DAG | Copy dags written by Dev team to airflow server continuously

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-emr, directed-acyclic-graphs

How can I continuously copy Dags written by Development team to airflow(`/home/ec2-user/airflow/dags`) server. I am using Ansible currently to install Airflow.

Current approach which I am using:-
I am asking dev team to push all the dags to `Bit Bucket` and I have  written a ansible script which picks up the dags and put in Airflow server. This is currently handled by Jenkins job which when triggered will copy to server.

Comment: Why there is an `ansible` tag? Ansible could not do anything 'continuously', it's not a server.

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin ok.. I thought there might be any solution via Ansible. So tagged it.